# OpenGL acceleration via SSH X11 forwarding or VNC viewer?

Tags: ssh, vnc, opengl

I am trying to run a proprietary OpenGL application remotely.  This application requires OpenGL acceleration and fails to run through X11 forwarding with either -X or -Y specified with the message

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  5531
  Current serial number in output stream:  5532
```

Other proprietary software gives the same error, however provides the `-mesa` option which forces software GL rendering.  I get this error with both X11 forwarding and when running TigerVNC on the :1 or :2 X server (both with and without iglx enabled).  I do not know of any way to run it on the :0 server and forward the output. Additionally, I have tried using VirtualGL to run the application, but VirtualGL cannot run due to the environment variables and libraries the proprietary software is enforcing.

Is there a way to run the application on :0 and forward the output over the network (or otherwise provide full GLX acceleration)?

Comment: To run on :0 you need a different vnc server. Package `X11vnc server` on debian.

Comment: x11vnc does appear to be much closer to what I want.  Unfortunately it can't lock the :0 due to the gdm greeter